How to dynamically import js modules in react typescript hosted on external URLs?
I have module hosted on external weburl
//  www.xyz.com/order.js
export function order() {
  const create = () => {
    console.log('Order created');
  };
  return { create };
}

I want to load this module dynamically in react typescript. I tried using
let module:any;
let configUrl = "www.xyz.com/order.js";
if(selectedModule === 'order'){
module = await import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ configUrl);
      console.log("module",module.create())
}

However this throws error
Unexpected token 'export'
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'


What about changing the file name to order.mjs?

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

interface OrderModule {
  order: () => {
    create: () => void;
  };
}

const DynamicImportExample: React.FC = () => {
  const [orderModule, setOrderModule] = useState<OrderModule | null>(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadModule = async () => {
      try {
        const configUrl = "https://www.example.com/order.js";
        const module = await loadExternalScript(configUrl);
        setOrderModule(module as OrderModule);
      } catch (err) {
        setError("Failed to load module: " + (err instanceof Error ? err.message : String(err)));
      }
    };

    loadModule();
  }, []);

  const loadExternalScript = (url: string): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = url;
      script.type = 'module';
      script.onload = () => {
        // Access the module through a global variable
        const module = (window as any).OrderModule;
        if (module) {
          resolve(module);
        } else {
          reject(new Error("Module not found after loading"));
        }
      };
      script.onerror = () => reject(new Error("Failed to load script"));
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
  };

  const handleCreateOrder = () => {
    if (orderModule) {
      const { order } = orderModule;
      order().create();
    }
  };

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error}</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Dynamic Import Example</h1>
      {orderModule ? (
        <button onClick={handleCreateOrder}>Create Order</button>
      ) : (
        <p>Loading module...</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default DynamicImportExample;```

